# Selenium IDE - Script stops running when asp.net validation mask encountered

Tags: asp.net, validation, selenium, mask

I've an asp.net form (wizard) with a phone number asp validation (textbox) that stops the Selenium test script as if the validation failed (upon playback). Upon recording the script, the validation worked fine, allowing the user to move to the next page with a valid phone number.

The Command Selenium decided to use was **clickAndWait** when recording the button select (to move-off the form); I changed it to use a suggestion found on this site:

"Try just using Click followed by WaitForElementPresent or something similar."

If anyone has another idea, I'd be very appreciative. There does not seem to be much out there regarding this issue. Surely forms are using asp.net validations.

Regards... Ed in Tampa